# Why apache-rat-plugin is enforced in Maven project?

Tags: maven

I have pom.xml https://pastebin.com/VDpgJ11K

```
<!--      <plugin>-->
<!--        <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>-->
<!--        <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--        <configuration>-->
<!--          <excludes>-->
<!--            <exclude>src/test/resources/bla.tar.xz</exclude>-->
<!--            <exclude>src/test/resources/empty.bin</exclude>-->
<!--            <exclude>src/test/resources/small.bin</exclude>-->
<!--            <exclude>m2</exclude>-->
<!--          </excludes>-->
<!--        </configuration>-->
<!--      </plugin>-->
```

with commented apache-rat-plugin (project: git clone —depth 1 —branch commons-codec-1.14 https://github.com/apache/commons-codec.git ) but rat-plugin still runs somehow when executing "mvn install", could you tell me why?
Thank you!

Comment: Please add the complete POM to the question itself.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier https://pastebin.com/VDpgJ11K

Comment: I saw the pastebin, but please just copy&paste the POM to the question.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier system said "too much code"

Comment: Have you looked into the parent POM?

Comment: @J Fabian Meier  no. Could you tell me how to access its source?

Comment: The parent POM is probably already in your local repository after the build. Otherwise have a look in the specified repositories. BTW: If you put spaces into my name, I won't be notified, so write please @JFabianMeier

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have solve my problem by uncommenting apache-rat-plugin in pom.xml then adding elements to <excludes> section of that plugin